# dateutil syntax error while deploying Flask Application

Tags: python, heroku, flask, deployment

I am trying to deploy a flask application (https://github.com/ihavemadefire/BestYearYet) using Heroku. When I deploy it it crashes immediately.  I can't tell if the redirect is telling me there is an error in my code (It runs perfectly on a local browser port), an error in my virtual env or if there is an error in an external library.

I have tried updating the appdirs and flask-dateutil libraries.  I have tried deploying from the Heroku git cli and from Github.  I checked my code to see if I missed something (but like I said, it runs fine locally)  I even tried rebooting.  I think this problem is beyond my experience level.

Here are the relevant error logs from Heroku (greatly truncated):

> File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/alembic/script/base.py",
>   line 7, in 
>        from dateutil import tz    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dateutil/tz.py", line
>   78
>        `self._name`,
>        ^

Comment: Have you tried to run a fresh copy of the repo in a new virtualenv? Try to mimic what Heroku does on deployment.

Comment: Simply setting `python-dateutil==2.8.1` in `requirements.txt` solved the issue for me. Heroku was using python-dateutil==1.5.0 which seemingly had compatibility issues with python-3.6.13. Upon pushing, Heroku gave this error `ERROR: heroku 0.1.4 has requirement python-dateutil==1.5, but you'll have python-dateutil 2.8.1 which is incompatible.`, and then showed installed python-dateutil-2.8.1 successfully. I don't know what happened here, but everything started working correctly! XD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Uninstall python-dateutil:**

```
pip uninstall python-dateutil
```

**And install the new version:**

*i use this version*

```
pip install python-dateutil==2.81
```

**see if you have the requirements.txt file, remember to change the version of python-dateutil there too, manually or try this:**

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

***if you don't have a requirements.txt, consider making one because it is "good practice" and is really helpfull***

Answer (score 0):

It looks like alembic depends on python-dateutil. In your `Requirements.txt` make sure alembic comes after the dateutil entry and try pushing the app to heroku again.

Comment: I moved the python-dateutil above alembic and it produced the same error.

Comment: I had the same error. The reason is that heroku has `python-dateutil==1.5.0` in the dependencies, which includes the deprecated syntax for python3.6